# How to make a customized GridView that is completely user defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

[image]

I have a `GridView`: 
On Button_Click
I want the first column of my `GridView` with the items of `ListBox1` and 2nd column with the EDIT link and from 3rd column on wards I want the headers as the items of `ListBox2`.

So far I am able to achieve EDIT link in the 2nd column and from 3rd column on wards the headers of the `GridView` with `ListBox2` items.

Now I want `ListBox1` items as the first column of my `GridView`. I have attached an image with show what exactly I want and what I have achieved so far.

Kindly help me on. Thank you.

The .cs code I have designed is:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow rw = default(DataRow);
        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox3.Items.Count; i++)
        {  dt.Columns.Add(ListBox3.Items[i].ToString(),System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            rw = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < ListBox3.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                rw[ListBox3.Items[i].ToString()] = " ";
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(rw);
        }
        GridView2.DataSource = dt;
        GridView2.DataBind();
```

The asp code for GridView is :

```
<Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Locations">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Lab1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
            </Columns>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a event of your `gridview_RowDataBound` 
and change value of your label

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

      Label lbl1= ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("Lab1"));
      lbl1.text = ListBox1.items[e.Row.RowIndex].ToString();
    }


}
```